# Display recent posts on front page

Tags: theme-development

I  am new to theme development in wordpress i am working on a theme, i have a front page on which i want to display only the most recent 4 posts of any category to be displayed my code for this is

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( ‘showposts=4′ ); ?>
        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <article>
        <a href=”<?php the_permalink() ?>”><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/post-images/Adithi_Dinner_blog.jpg" class="border" alt="image" /><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
        <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 100);?></p>
        <!-- <?php the_content( 'Read the full post »' ); ?>-->
        </article>
        <?php endwhile;?>
```

but it gives me error that unexpected "=", if i remove 4 from the showposts=4 than it shows all the posts on that page, kindly help me how i fix it, thanks

Comment: `showposts` is depreciated, should be using `posts_per_page`

Comment: Please don't use the wordpress.com tag. Please read the tag descriptions before using them. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 <?php 
            $args_latest = array(           
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'posts_per_page' => 4       
        );
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args_latest); ?>
            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <article>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/post-images/Adithi_Dinner_blog.jpg" class="border" alt="image" /><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
            <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 100);?></p>
            <!-- <?php the_content( 'Read the full post »' ); ?>-->
            </article>
            <?php endwhile;?>

<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Please check  if it works for you.

Comment: Please upvote my answer

Comment: I accepted it as correct but i have nu reputation right now to give u upvote hope u don't mind